# Enforce a rule that ensures cell groups hold unique values

Tags: excel, validation

Can I apply a rule in MS Excel to ensure cells C, D & E (for example) each have a different value from each other, for that row?

Comment: What is supposed to happen if they are not unique? Red background? Popup that disallows data entry? How many rows is this applied to? Show some sample data together with the expected results and what you have tried so far. Are you familiar with *Data Validation* or *Conditional Formatting*?

Comment: I was thinking a popup that disallows entry, it would be applied to every row. I'll mock up some sample data like you say. I've not tried much as I'm a total novice and have been googling for sometime trying to find help. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

C1 Data Validation: NOT(C1=D1), NOT(C1=E1)

D1 Data Validation: NOT(D1=C1), NOT(D1=E1)

E1 Data Validation: NOT(E1=C1), NOT(E1=D1)

Simpler than I thought :)